# Having trouble setting up OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

The following is code I got from a tutorial:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glcorearb.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <GL/gl_mangle.h>
#include <GL/glu_mangle.h>
#include <GL/GLwDrawA.h>
#include <GL/GLwDrawAP.h>
#include <GL/glxext.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>


void display() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0); glVertex3f(-0.6, -0.75, 0.5);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0); glVertex3f(0.6, -0.75, 0);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1); glVertex3f(0, 0.75, 0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

  glutInitWindowPosition(80, 80);
  glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
  glutCreateWindow("A Simple Triangle");

  glutDisplayFunc(display);

  glutMainLoop();
}
```

I included everything found in /usr/include/GL. I use RHEL 6.

I am getting the following errors:

```
In function ‘void display()’:
‘mglClear’ was not declared in this scope
‘mglBegin’ was not declared in this scope
‘mglColor3f’ was not declared in this scope
‘mglVertex3f’ was not declared in this scope
‘mglEnd’ was not declared in this scope
‘mglFlush’ was not declared in this scope
‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:25: error: ‘glutInit’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:26: error: ‘GLUT_SINGLE’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:26: error: ‘GLUT_RGB’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:26: error: ‘glutInitDisplayMode’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:28: error: ‘glutInitWindowPosition’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:29: error: ‘glutInitWindowSize’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:30: error: ‘glutCreateWindow’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:32: error: ‘glutDisplayFunc’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:34: error: ‘glutMainLoop’ was not declared in this scope
```

Does this mean that something is downloaded incorrectly or I am including wrong files?

Answer (score 1):

First of all install all the required libraries

```
 yum install mesa-libGL
 yum install mesa-libGL-devel
 yum install freeglut-devel
```

Next you need to actually compile everything correctly:

```
g++ *.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

And try to remove all those headers and replace it with

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including all those files, try to include only:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

Comment: So, how do you expect to use `glut`'s family functions? I suggest you to install this library.